# Hive Job Killed - IPC connection reset by peer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs, hadoop2

My hive script which has many queries fails at a specific point after execution of many queries.

Vanilla Hive version : 1.2.1
Execution Engine : mapreduce

In the logs I can see connection reset by one of the data node.
This issue is happening only sometimes and sometimes with this error the data-node gets rebooted.

Does it looks like just a network issue ?

or

Could it be memory related issues ? I am using hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask = true .
Could it cause heavy network traffic ?

Below is the log snippet, thanks in advance !!

```
 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_183782727_8787_m_000000_1 TaskAttempt Transitioned from NEW to UNASSIGNED
 INFO [Thread-50] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: 2 failures on node node3
 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: attempt_876576567_8787_m_000001_1 TaskAttempt Transitioned from NEW to UNASSIGNED
 INFO [Thread-50] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Added attempt_8787483787847_9124_m_000000_1 to list of failed maps
 INFO [Thread-50] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Added attempt_8787483787847_9124_m_000000_1 to list of failed maps
 INFO [Socket Reader #1 for port 46764] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Socket Reader #1 for port 46764: readAndProcess from client 160.43.98.11 threw exception [java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer]
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
 at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.channelRead(Server.java:2603)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.access$2800(Server.java:136)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Connection.readAndProcess(Server.java:1481)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.doRead(Server.java:771)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.doRunLoop(Server.java:637)
 at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener$Reader.run(Server.java:608)
 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerRequestor: getResources() for application_8787483787847_9124: ask=1 release= 0 newContainers=0 finishedContainers=0 resourcelimit=<memory:146608, vCores:1> knownNMs=5
 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Received completed container container_8787483787847_9124_01_000002
 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Received completed container container_8787483787847_9124_01_000003
 INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Before Scheduling: PendingReds:0 ScheduledMaps:2 ScheduledReds:0 AssignedMaps:2 AssignedReds:0 CompletedMaps:0 CompletedReds:0 ContAlloc:2 ContRel:0 HostLocal:1 RackLocal:1
 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_8787483787847_9124_m_000000_1: Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_8787483787847_9124_m_000000_1: Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
INFO [RMCommunicator Allocator] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator: Got allocated containers 2
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

Comment: *"sometimes with this error the data-node gets rebooted"* -- you mean that your query triggers a DN crash? or that you experience random DN crashes and some jobs (incl. your query) lose some conatiners?

Comment: If you really have a **server reboot** then investigate the Linux server logs on that machine. If you just meant that the **DataNode service dies** and has to be restarted then investigate the service logs on that machine.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for replying , I came to know from the Linux admins, the servers are configured to have a soft reboot if CPU load goes beyong 75%. I have no idea about this configuration.

Comment: WHAT??? **HDFS is a file system, for God's sake!** What do they do when a hard disk is 75% full: do they get it out of the server and hammer it down into pieces???